# How to Cache Text Area?

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, function

How would I go about caching text in a text area?

Using Javascript, I currently am able to create a text area:

```
var taid;

    var taid = document.createElement("textarea");
    taid.setAttribute("src", "");
    taid.style.width = "100%";
    taid.style.height = "100%";
    taid.style.border = "0px";
    taid.style.background = "lightblue";

    document.getElementById("sheet").appendChild(taid);
```

I'm quite new to Javascript. So I don't know to many functions. I'd like to use JSON stringify and cache all values in the textarea so that the values aren't lost when the page is refreshed. But any method in javascript would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Caching is really the wrong term here, I think. Check out [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: You could do `localStorage.setItem("value", taid.value)`

Comment: Caching is server-side, you're asking for a javascript solution which doesn't exist. You do have browser storage though, as the above comments have pointed out.

Comment: When I say caching, in my brain it's localStorage caching.

Comment: @Jonathan There's certainly such a thing as client-side caching. OP appears to want an "auto-save" sort of functionality, though, not caching.

Comment: @ceejayoz of course there is client side caching, if you’re referring to browser cache etc. But a cache in the sense of you can read-and-write to it at will, no there isn’t. Like you said, there is storage, but not caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the text in a database or in the localStorage of the browser and retrieve it on refresh. This will save the text in the textarea in the the `localstorage` on every keyup event, and when the window loads or reloads it will retrieve the data from the `localStorage` and store in the data variable. This variable will be the value of the textarea

```js
var data;
window.onload = function() {
  data = localStorage.getItem('data');
}
var taid;

var taid = document.createElement("textarea");
taid.setAttribute("src", "");
taid.setAttribute("onkeyup", "a()")
taid.style.width = "100%";
taid.style.height = "100%";
taid.style.border = "0px";
taid.style.background = "lightblue";
taid.value = data || "";

document.getElementById("sheet").appendChild(taid);

function a() {
  localStorage.setItem("data", taid.value);

}
```

```html
<body id="sheet"></body>
```

Comment: This pretty much worked but I did add an extra line in the onload. function, just setting the the textarea value to the var data.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `onchange` to the `textarea`, and save to `localStorage`, then load it back in when the page loads:

```
taid.addEventListener("change", () => {
    var text = taid.value;
    localStorage.setItem("text", text);
});

window.onload = () => {
    var savedText = localStorage.getItem("text") || "";
    taid.value = savedText;
};
```